# Add several dicts to a single dict

Tags: python

I have the following object:

```
obj = {}
```

I want to add a new object to `obj` , e.g:

```
"user": {
    "rights: 1,
    "players": [
        "1": "Ronaldo"
    ]
}
```

But in the end I want that `obj` looks like that:

```
{
    "user1": {
        "rights: 1,
        "players": [
            "1": "Ronaldo"
        ]
    },
    "user2": {
        "rights: 1,
        "players": [
            "2": "Messi"
        ]
    },
    "user3": {
        "rights: 1,
        "players": [
            "1": "Ronaldo"
        ]
    }
}
```

But I can't achieve that with obj.append, because then each object starts with its own {}, and I want that every object is in the header {}.
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: `obj["user1"] = {"rights: 1,
        "players": [
            "1": "Ronaldo"]}`

Comment: yes you can insert a new object with a key doing `obj[key] = new_object` where key is your key for this object ex: 'user1' and `new_object` is your object to store with defined key linke `{
        "rights: 1,
        "players": [
            "1": "Ronaldo"
        ]
    }`

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific function to add a new key:value pair to a python dictionary. Simply use the wished key as an index.

```
obj = {}

data = {
    "user1": {
        "rights": 1,
        "players": {
            "1": "Ronaldo"
        }
    },
    "user2": {
        "rights": 1,
        "players": {
            "2": "Messi"
        }
    }
}

for user in data.keys():
    obj[user] = data[user]
```

Comment: I need to do this with a for loop for 100 users. So I need somehow to append every new user to the dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

Just create a list and append to it:

```
users = []

my_dict = {"user": {
    "rights": 1,
    "players": [{
        "1": "Ronaldo"
    }]
}
}

users.append(my_dict)
```

Comment: The asker explicitly specifies that this is what he doesn't want to do.

Comment: if we talk about data, these are many single objects  together. "Writing because then each object starts with its own {}" looks like wrong read of the data you parse after.

Comment: I believe that was a roundabout way of saying that he wants the top level object to be a dict rather than a list.

Comment: same object structure * 100 in a loop. Going the way you think doesn't mean you are going right. But maybe you are right, he really wants it to not be a list